# MS Access 2013 VBA - Problem with period (".") in directory path

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013

I have some code to update a series of mdb files from a Master mdb file. The code pulls the directory address from a table in the Master. However, some of the directory names contain periods. This produces an error "Run-time error 3126 Invalid bracketing of name K:\DRUMSFILES\CARDINAL LÉGER JR. HIGH SCHOOL\JOB1_SJ3911 - SS\DATA\students].mdb"

The period in the "JR." causes the error. I have no control over the directory names.

I have tried double quotes and square brackets but haven't found a combination that works.

The is what the code looks like:

```
Dim sqlStr As String
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim rs As dao.Recordset

sqlStr = "SELECT SchoolFilePath from Jobs;"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)

rs.MoveFirst
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
Do While Not rs.EOF
  filePath = rs.Fields("SchoolFilePath") & "\students.mdb"
  strSQL = "DELETE FROM AddItems IN '" & filePath & "';"
  CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
  sqlStr = "insert into AddItems (Item1, Item2, Item3) IN '" & filePath & "' VALUES ('Retouch', 'Problem Orders', 'Class Photo/Memory Book');"
  Debug.Print sqlStr
  DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlStr)
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)
```

The debug line shows what the SQL line looks like. The last one errors off:

```
    insert into AddItems (Item1, Item2, Item3) IN 'K:\DRUMSFILES\CAMILLA SCHOOL\JOB1_MD3907 - 2PMB\DATA\students.mdb' VALUES ('Retouch', 'Problem Orders', 'Class Photo/Memory Book');
    insert into UserFields (User1, User2, User3) IN 'K:\DRUMSFILES\CAMILLA SCHOOL\JOB1_MD3907 - 2PMB\DATA\students.mdb' VALUES ('Problem Order', 'Family Plan', 'Late/Reorder');
    insert into AddItems (Item1, Item2, Item3) IN 'K:\DRUMSFILES\CAMILLA SCHOOL\JOB2_MD3907 - 1 - 2PMB - RTK\DATA\students.mdb' VALUES ('Retouch', 'Problem Orders', 'Class Photo/Memory Book');
    insert into AddItems (Item1, Item2, Item3) IN 'K:\DRUMSFILES\CARDINAL LÉGER JR. HIGH SCHOOL\JOB1_SJ3911 - SS\DATA\students.mdb' VALUES ('Retouch', 'Problem Orders', 'Class Photo/Memory Book');
```

Comment: I would suggesting organizing the data better, and not storing values within filenames.  Periods will cause problems in the filesystem in some situations and therefore should be avoided. More about naming files [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file).  (also are the CAPS really necessary?! :)

Comment: Did the test run using square brackets surround the entire filename??  or just the folder name that has the period?  I would suggest  'K:\DRUMSFILES\\[CARDINAL LÉGER JR. HIGH SCHOOL]\\[JOB1_SJ3911 - SS]\DATA\students.mdb'  because of the period and the embedded spaces.  Notice the double \\ needed before opening square bracket [

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the square brackets to no avail. I ran out of time, so I did a temporary bodge and removed the periods from the directory paths, ran my script and then added them back in.